# How can I convert .mov to mp4?

Tags: video, conversion, mp4

I have a .mov file I've just recorded that's 600MB, I want to convert it to a smaller .mp4 file. How can I do this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could try [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/). It's available on Windows/Mac/Linux.

It will re-encode your .mov file to a smaller .mp4 version. Note that you will always lose quality when re-encoding.

[image]

Comment: I've tried a lot of programs, handbrake is a very well polished app. Installed quick, and it seems to work so far.

Answer (score 3):

I think that the [mencoder](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/DOCS/HTML/en/mencoder.html) utility included with [mplayer](http://www.mplayerhq.hu) should be capable to handle both..

Answer (score 2):

**[SUPER ©](http://www.erightsoft.com/SUPER.html)** (Simplified Universal Player Encoder & Renderer) will convert pretty much any multimedia format (incl. MOV > MP4).

*SUPER © is freeware.*

Answer (score 2):

Another free option is ffmpeg, which is Free (as in freedom) and quite easy to use if you don't mind typing a few words at the command line. It's available for most operating systems--I can't be more specific unless you state which OS you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Try one of these:

1. [HandBrake](http://handbrake.fr/)
2. [MEncoder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MEncoder)

I think these two will help you with the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

[YAMB](http://www.videohelp.com/tools/YAMB) along with [MP4BOX](http://www.videohelp.com/tools/mp4box) is a good option.
Download both and unzip them (no installation needed and together they're about 5MB), in YAMB choose Settings and set the folder path of MP4box.

To convert a video file choose Creation > Create an MP4 file...

Comment: Tried Yamb on Windows 7, installed ok, but afterwards it gave an error when I selected the source file.

Comment: Works OK for me on win7 (64bit).